# How can I check which ports are busy and which ports are free on my Linux machine?

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora, port

Is there any command line command or any other way to find and list out the busy and free port numbers on my Linux machine?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The command

```
netstat -antu
```

will show all tcp and udp ports in use. The output will look something like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59753           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

The number after the colon in the Local Address field shows the port in use.  If the state is "LISTEN" it means a port that is using for incoming connections.  If the IP address in the `Local Address` field is `0.0.0.0` it means incoming connections will be accepted on any IP address assigned to an interface - so this means from connections originating outside of your machine.

If it said `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` it would be only accepting connections from your machine.

Additionally, if you add the `-p` parameter, and run it as root, it will show the process that opened the port:

```
$ sudo netstat -antup
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59753           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      860/rpc.statd
```

Anything not shown as being in use is free, however users (unprivileged accounts) can only open ports above 1023.

Comment: *it means incoming connections will be accepted **on any IP address assigned to an interface** - so this means from **connections originating outside of your machine*** didn't you make an error here? You probably meant, that connections will be accepted, if they come on any address assigned to a given interface, regardless of their origin. The origin of incoming connections is probably specified in the next column Foreign Address. So it's there, if one has 0.0.0.0 as a value, it means that the connections will be accepted from anywhere, including outside of the machine

Comment: @user907860 It might  not be clear, but the distinction I am making is between 0.0.0.0 vs 127.0.0.1 - the latter will only accept connections from your machine, because it is listening on an unrouted IP address. Where as 0.0.0.0 means any address on your machine, and so provided they are routed, connections can be made from other machines.

Comment: Just FYI, `-antu` can be written as `-tuna` 

Answer (score 18):

I compiled a [small list](http://adhocshare.blogspot.com/2012/10/find-list-of-open-ports-listening-ports.html) myself.

Some of my favorites are:

```
netstat -tulpn
lsof -i -n -P
```

Answer (score 8):

A good and reliable way to check for ports opened is using `ss` (replacement for the [deprecated](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/) `netstat`), it's usable in a script without requiring elevated privileges (i.e. `sudo`).

Usage: option `-l` for listening ports, option `-n` to bypass DNS resolution, and the filter on source port `NN`: `src :NN` (replace `NN` by the port you want to monitor). For more options, see `man ss`

```
ss -ln src :NN
```

Examples:

```
[user@server ~]# ss -ln src :80
State       Recv-Q Send-Q       Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      0      128                      *:80                *:*
[user@server ~]# ss -ln src :81
State       Recv-Q Send-Q       Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port
```

And in a script, using grep, we can test if the output contains the port we requested.
Example with port 80 in use  (see above):

```
myport=80
# count the number of occurrences of port $myport in output: 1= in use; 0 = not in use
result=$(ss -ln src :$myport | grep -Ec -e "\<$myport\>")
if [ "$result" -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Port $myport is in use (result == $result) "
else
  echo "Port $myport is NOT in use (result == $result) "
fi

# output:
Port 80 is in use (result == 1)
```

Example with port 81 not in use  (see above)

```
myport=81
result=$(ss -ln src :$myport | grep -Ec -e "\<$myport\>")
if [ "$result" -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Port $myport is in use (result == $result) "
else
  echo "Port $myport is NOT in use (result == $result) "
fi

# output:
Port 81 is NOT in use (result == 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
telnet localhost <PORT_NUMBER>
```

If the port is free you will get an error. If the port is in use telnet will connect.

(found on http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/8456-how-know-whether-particular-port-number-free-not.html)